# Fatal Exception : Main eclipse error

Tags: android, listview

This is my log cat :

[image]

It says `Fatal Exception : Main` and `res.resources` not found, and a lot of another errors. Whats going on?

This is my main activity :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private final static String highscore = "Your High Score : ";
private ListView listMenu;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
    ListMenu listMenuData[] = new ListMenu[]
    {
        new ListMenu(R.drawable.repetition, "Repetition\n" + highscore, 0)
    };
    
    ListMenuAdapter adapter = new ListMenuAdapter(this, R.layout.listmenu_item, listMenuData);
    
    listMenu = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listMenu);
    
    View header = (View)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listmenu_header, null);
    listMenu.addHeaderView(header);
    
    listMenu.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

This is the ListMenu, for setter-getter :

```
public class ListMenu {
public int icon, highscore;
public String title;

public ListMenu(){
    super();
}

public ListMenu(int icon, String title, int highscore){
    super();
    this.icon = icon;
    this.title = title;
    this.highscore = highscore;
}
```

And this is my ListMenuAdapter class :

```
public class ListMenuAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ListMenu> {
Context context;
int layoutResourceId;
ListMenu listmenu[] = null;

static class MenuHolder{
    ImageView imgMenuIcon;
    TextView txtTitle, txtHighScore;
}

public ListMenuAdapter (Context context, int layoutResourceId, ListMenu[] listmenu){
    super(context, layoutResourceId, listmenu);
    this.context = context;
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.listmenu = listmenu;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View row = convertView;
    MenuHolder holder = null;
    
    if(row == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        
        holder = new MenuHolder();
        holder.imgMenuIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imgMenuIcon);
        holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        holder.txtHighScore = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtHighScore);
        
        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else holder = (MenuHolder)row.getTag();
    
    ListMenu menu = listmenu[position];
    holder.imgMenuIcon.setImageResource(menu.icon);
    holder.txtTitle.setText(menu.title);
    holder.txtHighScore.setText(menu.highscore);
    
    return row;
}
```

I followed and modified my codes from this tutorial : [click here](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429)

**Some people said that `android.content.res.resources$NotFoundException` error can be fixed by cleaning the project/restart the Eclipse, but its NOT working for me**

Sorry for the long post, i really dont know what to do now
Thanks :D

Comment: The logcat stated line 52, which line is it on your `ListMenuAdapter`?

Comment: When i double click it, it comes to
holder.txtHighScore.setText(menu.highscore);
But why i cant double click the other?
THanks :D

Comment: because the other lines are not on your defined class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If so, then this is the problem. You should do :

```
holder.txtHighScore.setText(""+menu.highscore);
```

Since `menu.highscore` is `int`, it will invoke method `setText(int resId)` which loads the assossiated resource id that you defined on your `strings.xml`.

If you put `""+menu.highscore`, it will invoke `setText(CharSequence text)` which is what you want.

Comment: OMG...but when i checked it, it says that "int resid" is in the setText params, so why we must do ""+ ?
Anyway, this solved my problem..Thanks :D

Comment: that is `resId`, i have added explaination there.